# Selecting POSIX file based on file name

Tags: applescript

I'm having trouble accessing this file while trying to select it on the beginning characters basis...

```
set location to "/Users/myuser/Desktop/"
set bom to POSIX file (location & (first file of location whose name begins with "thisFile"))
tell application "Preview" to open bom
```

is it path/alias vs text type of a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `System Events` and the `Finder` know what a file in the file system is.
The Finder has a property `desktop` which points always to the desktop of the current user.

```
tell application "Finder" to set bom to first file of desktop whose name begins with "thisFile"
tell application "Preview" to open (bom as alias)
```

Or with an arbitrary POSIX path

```
set location to POSIX file "/Users/myuser/Desktop" as text
tell application "Finder" to set bom to first file of folder location whose name begins with "thisFile"
tell application "Preview" to open (bom as alias)
```

The `alias` coercion is needed because `Preview` doesn't recognize Finder file specifier objects.

Comment: I actually do need the location var in there as Desktop is just my temp testing location...

Answer (score 1):

[vadian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375060/45375) works well, but it's worth mentioning that:

- **you can get access to well-known folders even in the *default* context**,  *outside* the context of `System Events` and `Finder`; e.g.:

  - `path to desktop`
  - `path to home folder`
  - Use, e.g., `POSIX path of (path to home folder)` to get the POSIX path.
- **using context `System Events` is usually preferable to the `Finder` context, for reasons of both performance and predictability.**

With an arbitrary target folder, using a POSIX path:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
  set targetFolder to alias "/Users/jdoe/Desktop"
  # equivalent of: set targetFolder to (path to desktop)
  set targetFile to first file of targetFolder whose name starts with "thisFile"
end tell

tell application "Preview" to open targetFile
```

---

Alternatively, **if you know your way around the shell**, you could try:

```applescript
set targetFilePosixPath to do shell script "fls=(~/Desktop/*.pdf); printf %s \"$fls\""
tell application "Preview" to open (POSIX file targetFilePosixPath as alias)
```